# Android ViewBinding unable to render LinearLayout configuration

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-viewbinding

The ViewBinding implementation is unable to render the layout configuration for `LinearLayout` used in my code, while the same layout works with the older technique of `findViewById()`

I have setup the gradle to use ViewBinding

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
}
```

Below is the activity which uses a `LinearLayout`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ImageView
        ... />

  <Button
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

The corresponding Kotlin class includes the binding instance with its root view passed to `setContentView()`

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    ...

    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

While the Layout editor renders a correct alignment of the app, once it is launched onto the emulator the layout configuration such as `center_vertical` alignment set using `layout_gravity` of `LinearLayout` is ignored.

Is something incorrect or missing the way ViewBinding is implemented?

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my recyclerview. Did you manage to solve this one?

Answer (score 2):

in your `activity_main.xml`  give `id` to your `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, Solved with adding `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to `LinearLayout` in `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem doing an exercise in the "Developing Android Apps with Kotlin" course.

I did not find a solution because I suppose that without using view binding, a view above the one in main_activity.xml must be taken as root (probably the same full screen), so when using layout_gravity without view binding, it works, because it positions the LinearLayout relative to the screen. However, when using view binding, I assume that it takes the LinearLayout as its root, so layout_gravity does nothing (again, I'm not sure, I don't know very well how view binding works).

The solution I used was to simply try to achieve the same view with something different. For this in activity_main.xml I used:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: I can't explain why this ended up working for me but it did.  Maybe it was the `android:gravity="center_vertical"` vs `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

There are one possibility is that your `LinearLayout` have not any `id`.

When you are doing `binding.root` it keeps a reference of root view which is LinearLayout in your case.

As per the official document:

> If view binding is enabled for a module, a binding class is generated
>   for each XML layout file that the module contains. Each binding class
>   contains references to the root view and all views that have an ID.

Give id to your LinearLayout `android:id="rootView`, rebuild your project and try to run. 
I hope, it will solve your issue.

Thanks & Happy coding..!

Comment: I am working with Android Studio 4.0. The config you have provided works for Android Studio 3.6.This [blog article by Android developers](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc) suggests the build.gradle config has changed in the latest version.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: Tried that just now, still no luck. To add more details, I am able to manipulate the views inside the ViewGroup using the binding class instance, like `binding.myButton.setOnClickListener { ... }`. The only issue present is with the rendering of the layout properties of the ViewGroup